# MySQL: Delete statement from complex select subquery

Tags: mysql, join, select, delete

I would like to delete the output of the below SELECT command but I am not a DBA and my SQL knowledge is rather elementary. I want to delete the users matching the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT count()
    ,u1.username
    ,u1.real_name
    ,group_concat(u1.STATUS)
    ,group_concat(u1.options)
    ,min(u1.end_date)
    ,max(u1.end_date)
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ui.username
        ,max(end_date) AS max_end_date
    FROM users ui
    GROUP BY ui.username
    ) u2
    ON (u1.username = u2.username)
        AND (
            (u1.end_date = max_end_date)
            OR u1.STATUS = 'locked'
            )
WHERE u1.username NOT IN (
        'someuser1'
        ,'someuser2'
        )
GROUP BY username
HAVING count() > 1
    AND group_concat(u1.STATUS) LIKE '%active%'
ORDER BY username;
```

Comment: What are you trying to delete?

Comment: What is coming from that SELECT statement. The rows matching the SELECT. I will edit my question to emphasize on that. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/237729/edit) to include the tags relevant to the database system you're using.

Comment: So, are you trying to delete from the `Users` table where the `username` comes out of this `select` query?

Comment: Yes Scott, that's correct.

Comment: Also, update your question to indicate which RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) you are using.

Comment: @ScottHodgin I've updated the title and added a MySQL tag.

Comment: @Bluz - Thanks for updating the information - I don't know anything about MySQL, so someone else will have to answer your question.

Comment: No worries! Thank you for your help with the semantics:)

Comment: So it needs to delete users where STATUS = 'locked', username NOT IN (
        'someuser1'
        ,'someuser2'
        ), and STATUS LIKE '%active%'? Without being able to see the CREATE table it's a little hard to visualize it.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables accessed.  How many rows does the `SELECT` return?

Answer (score -1):

```
    DELETE FROM users u1 WHERE username IN
    (
        SELECT s1.username FROM
        (
            SELECT count()
                    ,u1.username
                    ,u1.real_name
                    ,group_concat(u1.STATUS)
                    ,group_concat(u1.options)
                    ,min(u1.end_date)
                    ,max(u1.end_date)
            FROM users u1
            INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT ui.username
                            ,max(end_date) AS max_end_date
                    FROM users ui
                    GROUP BY ui.username
                    ) u2
                    ON (u1.username = u2.username)
                            AND (
                                    (u1.end_date = max_end_date)
                                    OR u1.STATUS = 'locked'
                                    )
            WHERE u1.username NOT IN (
                            'someuser1'
                            ,'someuser2'
                            )
            GROUP BY username
            HAVING count() > 1
                    AND group_concat(u1.STATUS) LIKE '%active%'
            ORDER BY username
        )s1
    )
```

TRY THIS...

Comment: Answers that don't explain why they are appropriate are not well received.  Can explain why this is bit of code is the correct answer for the question?